# How to initialize each element of an array with a specific value at declaration?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I want to create an int array with 999 elements, each of which has value 999. Is there a way to initialize an int array during declaration instead of iterating through each element and setting its value to 999?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the array was small, e.g. only 3 items, you *could* do as follows::

```
int[] ints = { 999, 999, 999 };
```

But if it grows and [you don't want to repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), then better use [`Arrays#fill()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29). It hides the `for` loop away for you.

```
int[] ints = new int[999];
Arrays.fill(ints, 999);
```

Comment: This uses a for loop for you.  You can create a helper method which will create a new array filled with a value.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as you ask, you can however use `Arrays.fill()` to fill it and use an initialiser block to call that method:

```
class MyClass {
    private int [] myInts = new int[999];

    {
        Arrays.fill(myInts, 999);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it is:

```
int[] tab = {999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, ... };
```

You just have to type `999` for the number of elements you want, in this case 999 times)